# Swift ImageRenderer - Rendered view/PDF is empty

Tags: swift, swiftui, pdf-generation

I have the view that I'm trying to render into PDF using the iOS16+ approach described by Paul Hudson [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-render-a-swiftui-view-to-a-pdf).
It renders fine for static view.
But whenever I pass my real view - PDF is rendered empty.
Debug seems to show that **renderer** is empty.

**What I found is that if I remove ScrollView - it renders fine, but with ScrollView it doesn't.** What am I doing wrong?

## Parent view with render func:

```
import SwiftUI

@MainActor
struct CalculationsView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var currency: Currency
    
    var calculator: InvestmentCalculator
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            DetailedBreakdownTableView(calculator: calculator)
            .navigationTitle("Details")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .automatic) {
                    ShareLink("Export PDF", item: render())
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func render() -> URL {
        
        let renderer = ImageRenderer(content: 
                            DetailedBreakdownTableView(calculator: calculator)
                            .environmentObject(currency)
        )
        
        let url = URL.documentsDirectory.appending(path: "output.pdf")
        
        renderer.render { size, context in
            var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 600, height: 600)
            
            guard let pdf = CGContext(url as CFURL, mediaBox: &box, nil) else {
                return
            }
            
            pdf.beginPDFPage(nil)
            
            context(pdf)
            
            pdf.endPDFPage()
            pdf.closePDF()
        }
        
        return url
    }
    
}
```

## Rendered view:

```
struct DetailedBreakdownTableView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var currency: Currency
    var calculator: InvestmentCalculator
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Grid {
                // Header
                GridRow {
                    Text("Year")
                    Text("Principal")
                    Text("Dividends Earned")
                    Text("Portfolio Value")
                    Text("Profit")
                }
                .bold()
                
                Divider()
                
                // Rows
                ForEach(calculator.investmentData) { data in
                    GridRow {
                        Image(systemName: "\(data.year).circle.fill")
                            .frame(maxWidth: 50)
                        Text("\(data.principal,specifier: "%.0f") \(currency.currencySymbol())")
                            .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        Text("\(data.grossDividendsEarned, specifier: "%.0f") \(currency.currencySymbol())")
                            .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        Text("\(data.endingBalance, specifier: "%.0f") \(currency.currencySymbol())")
                            .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: .infinity)
                        Text("\(data.profit, specifier: "%.0f") \(currency.currencySymbol())")
                            .frame(minWidth: 60, maxWidth: .infinity)
                    }
                    Divider()
                }
            }
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
            .padding() // Padding around the entire Grid
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end I was able to find workaround. I've split table into its own view without scrollview and print that subview. Additionally, to print full content, I calculate page size based on table contents:
let totalHeight = (itemCount * itemHeight) + (padding * 2), and later use it in render:
var box = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: totalHeight).